# Xcode 8 beta 6 error: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator

Tags: ios, xcode

Anyone getting the following error with Xcode 8 beta 6: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator? Any advice how to eliminate it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more context in your question. Is this a runtime error in your app? A compile error? Something else? Provide more details and relevant code as appropriate.

Comment: It's a runtime error that I get when the following line of code is executed:         let count = self.backgroundMOC.countOfFetchObjects(entityName: "Distribution", predicate: nil)!

Comment: have the same problem, maybe this is beta case and will be fixed in stable version

Answer (score 6):

I saw the same error on performing performFetch on iOS 10.0.1:

```
- (void) refreshFetchedResults:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self configureFetchRequest:controller.fetchRequest];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![controller performFetch:&error]) {
            DDLogError(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
}
```

As reported [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60503), performing a save on the managedObjectContext associated with the NSFetchedResultsController **before** executing performFetch stops the warning from appearing. (In my case, there were changes to be saved.)

Comment: Sorry I must disagree with this solution. It might solve the problem, but there are many cases where one might not want to save a context to perform a fetch. Context save may be expensive if done often (compared to a fetch), and there are cases where you may want to mutate a context, fetch objects and discard the changes (not propagate to the parent context, in a multi-context environment). Though, I must admit, I can't find a solution to the same problem we're having… still investigating, will follow up if we find an answer :)

Comment: Agreed it may not be practical in all scenarios, but it addresses OP's question.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri I know this question is a bit old, but did you find a solution to this problem?